# Convert HTML To PDF With CSS

Tags: node.js, express, pdf, puppeteer

I have created one html page which is having external css. In my html page i have to display image as page border show that i have used **border-image** property in my web page. I have to place some content inside that border image. Everything is working properly in html page when it is rendered but now i want to convert this web page to pdf document for this i have used **node js, express, handlerbars, puppeteer**. while converting web page to pdf i have used handlebars template to render it but my css property(**border-image**) is not showing in pdf.

My project structure is below

[image]

**controller code**

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const fs = require("fs-extra");
const hbs = require("handlebars");
const path = require("path");

async function complie(){
  try{
    const filePath = path.join(__dirname,"../templates/index.hbs");
    const html = await fs.readFile(filePath,'utf-8');
    return hbs.compile(html);
  }catch(error){
    console.log(error);
  }
}

async function genratePDF(req,res){

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  const content = await complie();
    await page.setContent(content);
    await page.emulateMediaType("print");
    const pdfDocument = await page.pdf({
      path:"resume.pdf",
      format:"A4",
      printBackground:true
    });

    res.set("Content-Type","application/pdf");
    res.status(201).send(Buffer.from(pdfDocument,"binary"));
    await browser.close();
}
 module.exports.genratePDF = genratePDF
```

**Handlerbar code**

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  .box{
    margin: 100px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 700px;
    height: 800px;
    border: 30px solid;
    border-image-source: url("https://i.ibb.co/kKPjffN/frame.png");
    border-image-slice: 100;
    overflow: auto;
  };

   h1{
     color:green;
   }
  </style>
</head>
<body class="box">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

express configuration

```
const express = require("express");
const pdfroute = require("./routes/pdf");
const app = express();
app.use("/api/pdf",pdfroute);
app.listen(9000,() => console.log("Server is Running"));
module.export = app;
```

I have also tried to do same thing in **python/Django with pisa** but didn't get any success.